# Create a JSON object from a single PHP variable with key

Tags: php, json

I am trying to send a single PHP variable to a client via json. However, if I generate the string myself and pass it into json_encode, it adds / around the key. I am using:

```
$threadID = mysqli_insert_id($Thesisdb);
$threadtoJ='{"id":'.$threadID.'}';
echo json_encode($threadtoJ);
```

I am looking for an output like this: `{"id","12"}`

Comment: `echo json_encode(array("id" => 12));`

Comment: You want to *encode* your data to JSON, so you don't want to create the JSON yourself. You probably want to do something like this `["id" => $threadID]`, where you create an array, which you then encode with the function to JSON.

Comment: Your $threadtoJ already contains the desired result

Answer (score 3):

```
echo json_encode(array("id" => 12));
```

Is the correct answer. Thanks @u_mulder

Comment: Indeed, you need a regular array in php, then json_encode it, and you're on.